# How do I make a car model drivable?

Tags: animation

How can I animate a car driving? Is there a way to control the car like you would in a videogame?

Comment: This might be better fitted to a forum environment, like BlenderArtists as there is no specific question being asked, but a request for general recommendations and guidance, which doesn't work well in the SE format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some commercial solutions out there: A guy called blazraidr has a car rig, info is here:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBTVDEpwT5L3TXMYZO3Rn_g

I hold a completely finished car inluding a rig at my blendermarket portfolio; if you don't want to purchase it, you can have a look at the descripition video, which - if you take a close look - will show you how to setup such a rig:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mclrTtmJC0s&feature=youtu.be

finally, there is a simple rigged car at blendswap that might help:

http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/76077

Regards,

pixelpoems.de

Answer (score 1):

Fully working car driving example can be downloaded from here:
https://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/physics/types/vehicle.html

Just download the zip, open the .blend and hit P to drive.